# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '='.' on Datatable and object

Tags: c#, sql, syntax-error, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I've looked at a lot of similar questions on this site and elsewhere but none of them have helped me.

I'm trying to make a database connection with a query but I get the error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '='.'

on 2 different lines of code. I've tried to use spaces in the query around the = but that doesn't help.

Code 1 is:

```
string connectieString = dbConnection();

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectieString);

SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand();
select.Connection = connection;

select.Parameters.Add("@attackCategory", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = attackCategory;
select.Parameters.Add("@taughtOn", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = taughtOn;
select.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name FROM attackCategory = @attackCategory WHERE TaughtOn = @taughtOn";

using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(select.CommandText, connection))
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    return dt;
}
```

The exception is thrown on the `sda.Fill(dt);` line of code. This code works if no parameters are used in the query:

```
string cmd = @"select ID, Name from " + attackCategory + " where TaughtOn ='" + taughtOn + "'";
```

And code 2 is:

```
string connectieString = dbConnection();

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectieString);

SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand();
select.Connection = connection;

select.Parameters.Add("@attackCategory", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = attackCategory;
select.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
select.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM attackCategory = @attackCategory WHERE ID = @ID";

connection.Open();
object name = select.ExecuteScalar();
connection.Close();

return name;
```

The exception fires on the `object name = select.ExecuteScalar();` line of code. This code works if 1 parameter is used in the query:

```
select.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
select.CommandText = "SELECT Inhabitants FROM Planet WHERE ID=@ID";
```

Comment: The syntax of your SQL is incorrect. You haven't specified a table name. I suspect you mean something like `SELECT Name FROM SomeTable WHERE attackCategory=@attackCategory AND ID=@ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot provide table name has parameter, parameter applies in where clause with columns value.

```
string cmd = @"select ID, Name from " + attackCategory + " where TaughtOn ='" + taughtOn + "'";
```

but, we need to simplify to use parameter in this query.

```
SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand();
 select.Connection = connection;
 select.Parameters.Add("@taughtOn", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = taughtOn;
 string cmd = @"select ID, Name from " + attackCategory + " where TaughtOn  =@taughtOn"; 
 select.CommandText = cmd;
```

In the above tsql query, string concatenation applies and table name is included in the string, which will work.

**Edit:-**

I get it why you the sqlDataAdapter is not Recognizing the parameter.
Reason is you have not provided it. Yes, That's right you have provided the `CommandText` and not the Command Object which is of `select` variable.

I have corrected your code.

```
select.Parameters.Add("@taughtOn", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = taughtOn; 
string cmd = @"select ID, Name from " + attackCategory + " where TaughtOn =@taughtOn"; 
select.CommandText = cmd; 
select.Connection = new SqlConnection("provide your sql string");
using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(select)) 
{ 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
sda.Fill(dt); 
return dt; 
}
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: When I set the SQL command like in the text I get an error saying: Must declare the scalar variable "@taughtOn".' Which is the only variable that is declared.

Comment: You need to add it in the sql parameter, let me edit the answer.

Comment: @211086004 check the answer now

Comment: I still get the same error. But I've rewritten my code so that now all the values are selected by pressing buttons so I think I'm going to stop using parameters because now there is no risk of SQL Injection.

Comment: `select.Parameters.Add("@taughtOn", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = taughtOn;
            string cmd = @"select ID, Name from " + attackCategory + " where TaughtOn  =@taughtOn";
            select.CommandText = cmd;

            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(select.CommandText, connection))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                
                return dt;
            } `

Comment: @211086004 Could you tell me the what is the value in CommandText and the value of taughtOn variable ? you can check by putting a watch

Comment: CommandText = select ID, Name from AttackPhysical where TaughtOn  =@taughtOn
taughtOn = Earth

It seems to work but the sqlAdapter doesn't seem to recongnize it.

Comment: The sqlDataAdapter is not Recognizing the parameter ?

Comment: That seems to be the case because when looking at the compiler the parameter is set correctly and so is the command text. The sqlAdapter works fine if I use a command text that doesn't have parameters.

Comment: @211086004 I solved your problem !! check my edited answer

Comment: @211086004 Did you check the code after edit word ?

Comment: Yes it works perfectly. Thank you so much for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind object names like that. For object names, you'll have to resort to some sort of string concatenation. E.g.:

```
select.Parameters.Add("@taughtOn", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = taughtOn;
select.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name FROM " + attackCategory + " WHERE TaughtOn=@taughtOn";
```

**Note:**
This is an over-simplified solution that does nothing to mitigate the risk of SQL-Injection attacks. You'll need to sanitize `attackCategory` before using it like this.

Comment: @attackCategory is not been used in the query, what is the use of providing it as the parameter.

Comment: `QUOTENAME` is effective at mitigating injection for table names.

Comment: @SatishPai true 'dat. Copy-and-bug :-)

Comment: Thanks didn't know you couldn't use parameters for table names. Will see if I can get it to work using Quotename. But when I set the SQL command like in the text I now get an error saying: Must declare the scalar variable "@taughtOn".'